# How to get payer id from paypal via IOS MSDK2.x?

Tags: php, ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a question when using the Paypal IOS MSDK2.x in conjunction with Kount fraud checking.

Currently the MSDK2.x will return a payment confirmation in the delegate

```
"- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment"


 in this format of PayPalPayment class
{
  "client": {
    "environment": "sandbox",
    "paypal_sdk_version": "2.0.0",
    "platform": "iOS",
    "product_name": "PayPal iOS SDK;"
  },
  "response": {
    "create_time": "2014-02-12T22:29:49Z",
    "id": "PAY-564191241M8701234KL57LXI",
    "intent": "sale",
    "state": "approved"
  },
  "response_type": "payment"
}
```

where the info "Payer Id" is not included.

To work with Konut, the Kount server needs the "Payer Id" to be provided/updated in the inquiry. This "Payer Id" can be obtained if the payment request is made via web form where the paypal server will return a URL of this format

```
"http://<return_url>?paymentId=PAY-6RV70583SB702805EKEYSZ6Y&token=EC-60U79048BN7719609&PayerID=7E7MGXCWTTKK2"
```

My question is anyone know how to get the "Payer Id" if the payment request is sent from mobile device that runs IOS MSDK2.x?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have solved this problem. Just had not got time to update it here.

The steps to do this are:

1. Use the payment id to get the security token from here
   "https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
   Use "POST" with your paypal private token.
2. Use the security token to to get the payer id.
   https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/$your_payment_id"

You can use curl_setopt to do both steps on PHP. Hope this helps if anyone else has the same issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not getting the payer_id using this? Any other way??